# how to set response time in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a question about how to set the response timeout time for a server.

Currently, I met the issue that the server can't response within 2 minutes, and page will not get updated when server updated the data in background.

Because the performance from server side can't be improved now, so I want to expand the response time long enough.

And there was a issue I can't understand about. When the response timeout, the request will be sent to server again, I wanna know who is responsible for this.

Currently I was using Primefaces and Jboss.
Below is the callstack I got(this routine will repeat around every 2 minutes,with different thread id):

```
22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) java.lang.Exception: Stack trace

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.bel.rptvwr.business.ReportListBean.getReportList(ReportListBean.java:510)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.bel.rptvwr.business.ReportListBean.loadReportList(ReportListBean.java:570)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.bel.rptvwr.business.ReportListBean.refreshReportList(ReportListBean.java:77)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:131)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2486)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2168)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2116)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:288)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:246)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

22:13:11,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

22:13:11,223 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

22:13:11,223 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

22:13:11,223 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

22:13:11,223 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

22:13:11,223 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

22:13:11,223 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

22:13:11,223 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

22:13:11,223 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

There was no server side retry mechanism settings. so please help figure out.

Thanks,
levi

Comment: This issue is not PrimeFaces related imo... Or do I miss something?

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, I'm not sure what issue it should be currently, just know that because the server side performance is very low, will not response request in time. And the same request was re-issued. Could please help point out what the issue may be related, or where to set the timeout time to make client be more patient with the requests. I am very new with the web application development. Thanks, Levi

Comment: Make your code async and use polling/push to check if it is finished. That is architecually and technically a better solution